# GraphQL - how to write queries and mutations

Tags: typescript, graphql

I am trying to figure out how to make queries with graphql and am struggling to understand the error messages, or the principles that i must be misapplying.

I have an issue table in my prisma schema, with specific resolver and service to define queries in relation to issues.

My error messages are:

> Error 0: GraphQLDocumentError: Cannot query field "userId" on type
> "Mutation".
> at /Users/testing/packages/web/src/pages/issue.tsx:9:5
>
> Error 1: GraphQLDocumentError: Cannot query field "issueId" on type
> "Issue".

In my resolver, I have:

```
import { Arg, Mutation, Query, Resolver } from "type-graphql"
import { Issue } from "./issue.model"
import { IssueService } from "./issue.service"
import { IssueInput } from "./inputs/create.input"
import { Inject, Service } from "typedi"

@Service()
@Resolver(() => Issue)
export default class IssueResolver {
  @Inject(() => IssueService)
  issueService: IssueService

  @Query(() => [Issue])
  async allIssues() {
    return await this.issueService.getAllIssues()
  }

  @Query(() => [Issue])
  async allClimateChangeIssues() {
    return await this.issueService.getAllClimateChangeIssues()
  }


  @Query(() => Issue)
  async issue(@Arg("id") id: string) {
    return await this.issueService.getIssue(id)
  }

  @Mutation(() => Issue)
  async createIssue(@Arg("data") data: IssueInput) {
    return await this.issueService.createIssue(data)
  }
}
```

In my issue service, I have:

```
import { prisma } from "../../lib/prisma"
import { Service } from "typedi"
import { IssueInput } from "./inputs/create.input"
import { Resolver } from "type-graphql"
import { Issue } from "./issue.model"

@Service()
@Resolver(() => Issue)
export class IssueService {
  async createIssue(data: IssueInput) {
    return await prisma.issue.create({ data })
  }

  async getAllIssues() {
    return await prisma.issue.findMany()
  }

  async getAllClimateChangeIssues() {
    return await prisma.issue.findMany({where: {issueCategory: "CLIMATE_CHANGE"}}) 
  }

  async getIssue(id: string) {
    return await prisma.issue.findUnique({ where: { id } })
  }
}
```

When I try to run the codegen to make the types, I get the above error messages.

Is there an extra step I need to do to be able to add a userId to an issue mutation (users are defined in a differnt table of my prisma schema, with a relation reference). I don't understand why i cant have an id field in my issue query.

I know the codegen is probably a precondition to being able to use these things, but in my form, and view, I am trying to use gql as follows:

```
const _ = gql`
  mutation CreateIssue($data: IssueInput!) {
    createIssue(data: $data) {
      id
      title
      issueCategory
      description
    }
    userId
  }
  query AllIssues {
    allIssues {
      # id  --- I tried commenting this line in case it was the source of the error message above, but it doesnt change anything.
      title
      issueId
      description
      userId
    }
  }
  query AllClimateChangeIssues {
    allClimateChangeIssues  {
      id
      title
      description
    }
  }
`
```

I can see that the createIssueMutation has a userId in its fiels:

```
export type CreateIssueMutation = { __typename?: 'Mutation', createIssue: { __typename?: 'Issue', id: string, title: string, issueCategory: Category, description: string, userId: string } };
```

I cannot find a way to generate the codegen for the useAllClimateChangeIssuesQuery.

The assumed knowledge on apollo and typescript FAQ pages starts at a level more advanced than that which I can find a way to build toward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your mutation:

```
  mutation CreateIssue($data: IssueInput!) {
    createIssue(data: $data) {
      id
      title
      issueCategory
      description
    }
    userId
  }
```

Notice the scope of userId, it's set outside of the createIssue operation.

Some advice double check your GraphQL schematic to see what is actually expected.

Comment: I thought doing it this way would let me add the userid without letting the user input it directly

Answer (score 0):

You just have a typo:

```
  mutation CreateIssue($data: IssueInput!) {
    createIssue(data: $data) {
      id
      title
      issueCategory
      description
      userId
    }
  }
```